# Sql Compact to another database

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, sql-server-ce

What are my options if I decide to give up using SQL Compact 3.5 on client side considering I have a small amount of SQL queries that needs to be converted to target database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move your schema and data to SQL Server, you may use this nice [tool](http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/)